# Remove LFS files in Github Repo

Tags: github, git-lfs

I have been pushing many branches to the Github repo using LFS. At the time I found out how to use LFS, I did not know that it keeps track of all the files from all branches. In the past 2 weeks I am not able to push my new branches anymore due to out of Quota. How do I remove all of the files from LFS so I can make my new branch be pushed again?
Github provided this link for deleting unwanted files but I don't know how to implement it in this case to just remove LFS files: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository